# Windows Vista Can't Install Applications such as VMWare Player

Tags: windows, windows-vista, installation

I'm trying to install several programs such as Juniper Client and VMWare player.  Especially for VMWare Player, if I double-click on the application, a DOS window just pops up and rapidly disappears.  For a program like Juniper Client, it appears to unzip but then it just dies.  If I run these programs directly through the command line as admin, no error / nothing is printed, it just dies.

Any idea where / what logs I can look at?  Better yet, any solutions are always welcome

Comment: It seems that the files you're trying to open are corrupted. Compare your VMWare setup file checksum with the one available on VMWare website for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe running the program as an administrator should resolve the problem, no? Also, just like fardjad recommended, I would check for corruption.

A better place to look for solutions regarding VMWare might be here: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/70315

I have had issues such as the one you are having - I had to clean my cache, re-download the document/software after removing corrupted versions and running as admin.

Hope this helps a little...